# Access 2007 error in wizard generated query for finding duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to use the query wizard to generate a query for finding duplicate records. The query generated worked fine with a table, but when I apply the wizard again to run find duplicates in a query I keep getting this error:
: "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression...as part of an aggregate function".
here is the SQL generated by the wizard:

```
SELECT [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code], [four letter c-codes].[bird_data_ID], [four letter c-codes].[Metal_ID]
FROM [four letter c-codes]
WHERE ((([four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code]) In (SELECT [4_letter_code] FROM [four letter c-codes] As Tmp GROUP BY [4_letter_code] HAVING Count(*)>1 )))
ORDER BY [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code];
```

I tried to execute the In clause separately and it worked, outputting the duplicate values for field [4_letter_code]. Replacing the In clause by the constants yielded thereby also gave the desired output.
Would appreciate any help to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just removed the redundant parenthesis, try this...

```
SELECT  [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code] ,
        [four letter c-codes].[bird_data_ID] ,
        [four letter c-codes].[Metal_ID]
FROM    [four letter c-codes]
WHERE   [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code] IN (
        SELECT  [4_letter_code]
        FROM    [four letter c-codes]
        GROUP BY [4_letter_code]
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1 )
ORDER BY [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code];
```

OR, you could try an `INNER JOIN`...

```
SELECT  [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code] ,
        [four letter c-codes].[bird_data_ID] ,
        [four letter c-codes].[Metal_ID]
FROM    [four letter c-codes]
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT [4_letter_code]
                     FROM   [four letter c-codes]
                     GROUP BY [4_letter_code]
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                   ) b 
             ON [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code] = b.[4_letter_code]
ORDER BY [four letter c-codes].[4_letter_code];
```

Comment: The WHERE clause still did not work, yielding the same error message (I have no clue why...); however the alternative code using INNER JOIN worked! Thanks!

Comment: @user3907312, glad it worked - you can mark it as the answer if that's the case.

Comment: the inner join approach is a great work around to failing sql generated by the wizard, thanks!